# How to disable decompiler view in Eclipse (Eclipse EE 2021-06 version)

Tags: eclipse, java-8

I want to disable decompiler view in eclipse workspace, I enabled it by 'Window > Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations and for the *.class file and *.class file without source type changed default associated editor to Class Decompiler Viewer (from Class File Viewer). But when I do the reverse it still showing decompiled view of class files. I don't want to view that, I just want to view the jar file to which that class belongs. Share your suggestions on disabling it.

Comment: The _reverse_? Please give step-by-step instruction how to reproduce it, show a screenshot of what you actual have and describe what you exactly want instead. A link of the decompiler plugin you installed and you are talking about would also be helpful since it is not built-in.

Comment: Removing the decompiler functionality won't let you "view the jar file to which that class belongs".  It'll simply give you some metadata about the class file.